# How do I Hangup up call in Asterisk Event

Tags: python, asterisk

I am connecting to Asterisk server using Python Asterisk manager. How do I hangup calls from the AMI.

```
def hangup_event(event, manager):
with ctx:

    if event.name == 'Hangup':
        data = {
            "channel":event.message['Channel'],
            "unique_id":event.message['Uniqueid'],
            "cause":event.message['Cause'],
        }

 manager.register_event('*', hangup_event)
 channel = 'SIP/356256266262'
 res = manager.send_action({'Action':'Hangup', 'Channel':channel})
```

My objective is to end the call but it isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

Use ami action COMMAND. Issue command

```
channel request hangup channel_name_here
```

Comment: I don't get you @arheops. Help me write it in code.

Comment: Acordinly to guidlines you have show effort in writing code. Sorry, i am not expert in lib you are using(you even not informed us about), i am expert in asterisk.

Comment: Anyway i already answered your question. You can wait for second answer or understand this one

Comment: Now the Asterisk AMI has been working and suddenly it stops working yesterday. I don't know what went wrong but I noticed it is taking a lot of time to connect and eventually gives a 502 bad gateway